# Type Error on Change Event

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some issues with an Excel VBA script. I'm trying to set it up to where a time stamp forms when data is entered into the first column, but delete the row when the first cell is deleted.

An Error 13 keeps popping up, but I can't see where the type is mismatched. I've tried:

Defining a separate `Range` type variable as `Target`

Setting Target.Column and Target.Row as separate variables

Using a For loop

Using a For Each loop

Using a With loop

All of it keeps throwing the Error 13. Below is is my code, and any help would be appreciated.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value2 <> "" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Format(Date, "ddd mmm d, yyyy")
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm")
        ElseIf Target.Value2 = "" Then
            Target.EntireRow.Value = ""
        End If

    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Leave screenupdating off until you have it fixed and step thru code one line at a time until you pinpoint the line it's on - then report back or maybe the problem will be obvious then. Can you set EntireRow to "" - or do you have to use ClearContents?

Comment: Don't forget that `Target` is a `Range` and as such may consist of multiple cells which creates a problem for something like `If Target.Value2 <> "" Then`. You might want to implement an outer loop along the line of `For Each cell in Target` ...

Comment: @Ralph         Thank you for the comment. I managed to get it to work with the answer below and used your comment to work in multi-line deletion. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable Events before making changes to cell via VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value2 <> "" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Format(Date, "ddd mmm d, yyyy")
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm")
        ElseIf Target.Value2 = "" Then
            Target.EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I'm guessing that with the events turned on, it was getting stuck in a self referential loop. Thank you!